# Venia pwa + magento 2

Tags: magento2, graphql, pwa, venia, magento-graphql

Can anyone explain how security works on graphql on venia pwa? I don't see any tokens or sessions or something like this at Venia. So any developer can create a graphql query and get all data from my site?

Comment: means all your data show on pwa site from magento 2 site

Comment: @mohitvamja 
For example i have venia  www.pwa.com and magento www.magento.com, i am an external user that dont know credentials, can i use graphql query via url www.magento.com/graphql and get all data that i need ?
If i can't so why? How graphql security is works? is that my question:D

Comment: i have created module you can understand better.

Comment: @mohitvamja and where i can see it ?

Comment: wait i will share this now can you used discord.?

Comment: no, can you just send me on gmail, please? lionkis13@gmail.com 
@mohitvamja

Comment: please check i will share my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have alredy one module for my custom grid in backend site so I will share my screenshot.

[image]
[image]

now I will share my code for graphql related.

/var/www/html/walletmetamask/app/code/Test/Uiform/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Test_Uiform" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_GraphQl"/>
        <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

/var/www/html/walletmetamask/app/code/Test/Uiform/etc/schema.graphqls

```
type Query {
getDemoLink : [getAllGridDemo] @resolver( class: 
 "Test\\Uiform\\Model\\Resolver\\GridRecords") @doc(description: "Get 
 All  Banners")
}

type getAllGridDemo {
blog_id : Int  @doc(description: "Blog Id"),
name : String  @doc(description: "name"),
status : String  @doc(description: "Status"),
category : String  @doc(description: "category"),
image : String  @doc(description: "image"),
cars : String  @doc(description: "image")
}
```

/var/www/html/walletmetamask/app/code/Test/Uiform/Model/Resolver/GridRecords.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Uiform\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
```

class GridRecords implements ResolverInterface
{
private $GridRecords;

```
public function __construct(
    \Web30india\Uiform\Model\Resolver\DataProvider\GridRecords 
$GridRecords
) {
    $this->GridRecords = $GridRecords;
}

public function resolve(
    Field $field,
    $context,
    ResolveInfo $info,
    array $value = null,
    array $args = null
) {
    $GridRecords = $this->GridRecords->getGridRecords();
    return $GridRecords;
}
}
```

/var/www/html/walletmetamask/app/code/Test/Uiform/Model/Resolver/DataProvider/GridRecords.php

```
<?php

namespace Web30india\Uiform\Model\Resolver\DataProvider;

class GridRecords
{
private $BlogFactory;

public function __construct(
      \Web30india\Uiform\Model\BlogFactory $BlogFactory
 ) {
      $this->BlogFactory = $BlogFactory;
 }

public function getGridRecords()
{
    try {
        $collection = $this->BlogFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $Records = $collection->getData();
        foreach ($Records as &$record) {
            // Assuming 'status' is the key for the status field in the record
            $status = isset($record['status']) ? $record['status'] : null;

            // Check the status and set 'enable' or 'disable'
            if ($status == 1) {
                $record['status'] = 'enable';
            } else {
                $record['status'] = 'disable';
            }
        }

    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(__($e->getMessage()), $e);
    }
    return $Records;
}
}
please check below screenshot forhow to open graphql on browser and add your project URL.
```

[image]

here my project url => http://127.0.0.1/walletmetamask/pub and last add graphql http://127.0.0.1/walletmetamask/pub/graphql so you can add your project url and after end add graphql

next screen shot for run my code so plese apply query for your module data related.

```
{
  getDemoLink{
    blog_id
    name
    status
    category
    image
    cars
 }  
}
```

[image]

i hope that is help for you. if you like then accept my answer and upvote.

Comment: thanks for your answer but,
as i see, you just showed me how to use graphql, sorry but i know it :( 
my question is: how securty works here?
if you have this data on server, i can use this graphql query and stole these data?